I have bleach residue on deck after cleaning
I thought I was ready to stain with semi solid stain over previous semitransparent stain.  I am noticing a residue that I believe may be left from cleaning with 30 second cleaner and added bleach. Now I am wondering if I need to neutralize the surface before I stain again. The surface still has old stain in areas where it is still adhering well to surface and 30% of surface is older pressure treated wood. I am planning to flush and scrub the surface with boiled water and scrub but not sure if I should neutralize too. Thanks

To add information to your question, Edit the question or add a Comment to it and so eond will probably help you edit that in. Answers should be used only for actual proposed solutions.
